# Where to put the destructor code for an ATL COM object?

Tags: c++, com, destructor, atl

Where does the destructor code for things I have defined in an ATL COM object belong?

Should it go in `~MyComClass()` or in `MyComClass::FinalRelease()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as `FinalRelease` is in question, I assume your question is related to ATL.

In most cases you can clean things up in either of the two. `FinalRelease` will be called immediately before the actual destructor. The important difference is that if you aggregate other objects, FinalRelease gives you a chance to clean the references and release dependencies before actual destructor of top level COM object class (esp. `CComObject`) starts working.

That is, you clean things up in two steps, first references to aggregated objects in `FinalRelease` and then other things in either `FinalRelease` or destructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general approach:

```
MyComClass::~MyComClass()
{
    // Cleanup object resources in here.
}

ULONG __stdcall MyComClass::Release()
{
    ref_count_--;

    if (0 == ref_count_)
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }

    return ref_count_;
}
```

*EDIT: `FinalRelease()` appears to be related to ATL which I am unfamiliar with.*

Comment: Than you.  The ATL wizard has not added a `::Release()` method to my class, yet presumably this reference counting is going on somewhere?  How can I find it?

Comment: @SideshowBob, sorry but I have never used the ATL wizard so I cannot comment on what it does. Roman R. seems to be familiar with it given his answer.

Comment: ATL generally uses `new CComObject<T>`, which inherits from `T` and adds implementations for `AddRef` and `Release` in the most derived class -- this way, the `delete this;` works correctly with a non-virtual destructor.

Comment: You should never implement Release() manually, when you are using ATL. As Simon Richter wrote, it is implemented by CComObject<T>.